# How to used the T-SQL to do the minus between two column in SQL server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have one table named **Employee** in SQL Server:

```
Employee   Clock-In                  Clock-Out
111        11/4/2019 2:31:08 PM      11/4/2019 4:31:08 PM
112        11/4/2019 2:31:08 PM      12/4/2019 2:31:08 PM
```

I wish to have a new column in this **Employee** table which is **Duration**: (below is my expected table)

```
Employee   Clock-In                  Clock-Out                 Duration(day)
111        11/4/2019 2:31:08 PM      11/4/2019 4:31:08 PM      0
112        11/4/2019 2:31:08 PM      12/4/2019 2:31:08 PM      1
113        13/4/2019 2:31:08 PM                                2
```

The **Duration(day)** column data will be auto calculate by using the **Clock-Out** column **minus** the **Clock-In** column; however if the Clock-Out time is empty, it will take the current datetime minus the Clock-In column. For example the current datetime is 15/4/2019 2:31:08 PM.

Anyone have ideas on this?

Comment: You day count is 24 hours long? Does a full day count if it's between 11pm and 2am next day?

Comment: yes count for 24 hours long

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `DATEDIFF`, not with `DAY` but with `MINUTE` or `SECOND`. The following example returns 1 day but the amount of time is actually 2 seconds:

```
SELECT
    DATEDIFF(
        DAY,
        '2019-01-01 23:59:59',
        '2019-01-02 00:00:01')
```

`DATEDIFF` with `DAY` will not take into account the time portion, it will only look at the day difference.

So you can use a lower degree to measure a full day, like minutes or seconds:

```
DECLARE @FirstDate DATETIME = '2019-01-01 23:59:59'
DECLARE @SecondDate DATETIME = '2019-01-03 05:00:00'

SELECT
    SecondDifferences = DATEDIFF(SECOND, @FirstDate, @SecondDate),
    FullDaysBySecond = DATEDIFF(SECOND, @FirstDate, @SecondDate) / 86400, -- 86400 = 24*60*60

    MinuteDifferences = DATEDIFF(MINUTE, @FirstDate, @SecondDate),
    FullDaysByMinute = DATEDIFF(MINUTE, @FirstDate, @SecondDate) / 1440, -- 1440 = 24*60

    DayDifferences = DATEDIFF(DAY, @FirstDate, @SecondDate) -- Wrong, not full 24 hours days!
```

Result:

```
SecondDifferences   FullDaysBySecond    MinuteDifferences   FullDaysByMinute    DayDifferences
104401              1                   1741                1                   2
```

So the `ALTER` would be:

```
ALTER TABLE Employee ADD Duration AS DATEDIFF(
        MINUTE, 
        [Clock-In], 
        ISNULL([Clock-Out], GETDATE())) 
    / 1440
```

You won't be able to persist this column because `GETDATE()` is non-deterministic and SQL Server won't let you, meaning that this will be computed every time it is queried.

Answer (score 3):

use `datediff()` and `coalesce()`

```
select employee,
ClockIn,ClockOut,
datediff(day,ClockIn,coalesce(ClockOut,getdate())) as duration
from table_name
```

for that you can create a view like below

```
create view view_name AS
select employee,
ClockIn,ClockOut,
datediff(day,ClockIn,coalesce(ClockOut,getdate())) as duration
from table_name
```

Comment: Be careful with the `DATEDIFF` with `DAY`, it won't always return full 24 hour days. More info on my answer.

Comment: Hi, with your query I have get the correct data that I want but this is in select statement, which is able view only, however any ideas can direct store it in database? I face the problem on auto update directly to the sql server, mean this query will be keep on running so that duration column show latest result

Comment: @ShiJieTio hey for that you can create a view i have edited answer

Answer (score 0):

use `datediff()` and sql server `isnull()` function, since your `columns` are with `dash`, you need to escape it.

```
select Employee
  , [Clock-In]
  , [Clock-Out]
  , datediff(dd, [Clock-In], isnull([Clock-Out], getdate())) as Duration
from Employee
```

Comment: You have to delimit the column names with a dash character.